# How would I create a way around password confirmation and email confirmation?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Hello I have built a fully working form with ajax, jquery but I have come across a little problem.

Here is my code...

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Login Details</legend>
<label>Your Email:</label><input id="email" name="email" type="text" onchange="return signup_ajax ('#email');" />
<label>Confirm Email:</label><input id="cemail" name="cemail" type="text" onchange="return signup_ajax ('#cemail');" />
<label>Password:</label><input id="password" name="password" type="text" onchange="return signup_ajax ('#password');" />
<label>Confirm Password:</label><input id="cpassword" name="cpassword" type="text" onchange="return signup_ajax ('#cpassword');" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Account Details</legend>
<label>Your Username:</label><input id="username" name="username" type="text" onchange="return signup_ajax ('#username');" />
</fieldset>

<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Create Account" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY**

```
function signup_ajax (id) {
var val = $(id).val();
$(id).after('<div class="loading"></div>');
if (id === '#email') {
    $('#email_error, #email_success').hide();
    $('.loading').delay(1000).hide(1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.post('http://www.example.com/ajax.php', {email: val},
        function (response) {
            finish_ajax (id, response);
        });
    }, 1050);
}
if (id === '#cemail') {
    var cemail_val = $('#email').val();
    $('#cemail_error, #cemail_success').hide();
    $('.loading').delay(1000).hide(1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (val !== cemail_val) {
            $(id).after('<div id="cemail_error" class="error">Emails do not match</div>');
        }
        else {
            $(id).after('<div id="cemail_success" class="success">Emails match</div>');
        }
    }, 1050);
}
if (id === '#password') {
    $('#password_error, #password_success').hide();
    $('.loading').delay(1000).hide(1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (val.length < 6) {
            $(id).after('<div id="password_error" class="error">Must be at least 6 characters</div>');
        }
        else {
            $(id).after('<div id="password_success" class="success">Success</div>');
        }
    }, 1050);
}
if (id === '#cpassword') {
    var cpassword_val = $('#password').val();
    $('#cpassword_error, #cpassword_success').hide();
    $('.loading').delay(1000).hide(1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (val !== cpassword_val) {
            $(id).after('<div id="cpassword_error" class="error">Passwords do not match</div>');
        }
        else {
            $(id).after('<div id="cpassword_success" class="success">Passwords match</div>');
        }
    }, 1050);
}
if (id === '#username') {
    $('#username_error, #username_success').hide();
    $('.loading').delay(1000).hide(1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (val.length < 3) {
            $(id).after('<div id="username_error" class="error">Must be at least 3 characters</div>');
        }
        else {
            $.post('http://www.example.com/ajax.php', {username: val},
            function (response) {
                finish_ajax (id, response);
            });
        }
    }, 1050);
}
} 

function finish_ajax (id, response) {
      $(id).after(response);
}
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_REQUEST['email']));
if (!filter_var($_REQUEST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo '<div id="email_error" class="error">This is not a valid email</div>';
}
elseif ($q -> rowCount() > 0) {
    echo '<div id="email_error" class="error">Email already owns an account</div>';
}
else {
    echo '<div id="email_success" class="success">Success</div>';
}
}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_REQUEST['username']));
if ($q -> rowCount() > 0) {
    echo '<div id="username_error" class="error">Username already taken</div>';
}
else {
    echo '<div id="username_success" class="success">Success</div>';
}
}
else {
header('Location: http://www.projectv1.com');
exit();
}
```

When a user enters a password that is not of the required length all works well. But if a user then continues to confirm the password with the same value as the previous password it will come up with passwords match as expected. But as the first one is incorrect they go back and change the first but the second still says it is a match how can I make it check it again if the value of id password is changed??

Same with email, if this makes sense??

Thanks for your time...

Comment: have you considered using a pre-fab'd validationEngine? like http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/ I use this engine and it works very well. Also lets you make conditional validation checks.

Comment: This would be good, but I like to understand what is going on and building my own is doing just that. Thanks though :)

Comment: another "debug my code for me" question...

Comment: Not touching the answer, but you'd be better off filtering the email value BEFORE you try and hit the database. No point in querying for an email address that you know to be invalid.

Comment: No my code works fine, I was asking how to improve the functionality of my code as I have no idea of where to begin with the question I asked in mind.

Comment: @carlgcode You can learn a great deal from looking at the source code of the top jQuery validation plugin as they are written by highly experienced developers and are tried and tested in countless production projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your code from above:

```
if (id === '#password') {
    $('#password_error, #password_success').hide();
    $('.loading').delay(1000).hide(1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (val.length < 6) {
            $(id).after('<div id="password_error" class="error">Must be at least 6 characters</div>');
        }
        else {
            signup_ajax ('#cpassword');
        }
    }, 1050);
}
```

But I would also recommend to use one of the already mentioned jQuery form validation plugins. And even if you still want to write your own validation, take a look at the code of one or two of these plugins, they will give you lots of ideas on how to do what you are doing here in a much better way.

Comment: Thank you for this, such a simple answer works great :) Good idea about looking at the code

Comment: @carlgcode If this answer helped you please consider marking it as an answer or voting for it. Thanks.

Comment: Had to fiddle around a little bit with the layout of the if & else statements but works great thanks dude!, and I had to wait to be able to accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

wouldn't using the jquery validation solve your problem,
such a plugin would do all this for you, even when 2 validations collide...

read more about it here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

and see demo's here:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tend to learn nothing using plugins, I would like to try and build it on my own and understand the process before using plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem you are asking about is that you cannot ONLY do validation of a field in the `onchange` event because you have two fields that depend upon one another so when one changes, you have to validate both of them.  Anytime, you change the password field, you have to also validate the confirm password field and vice versa.  And, you will have to handle an empty confirmation field gracefully when the user hasn't gotten there yet.

And, you should validate everything before submitting the form and not submit the form if anything fails validation.

Comment: Thanks for this, yes I will do all the proper form validation with php :)

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my answer.  When the user changes the password field, you need to call both `signup_ajax ('#password')` and `signup_ajax ('#cpassword')`.  That will solve the problem you were specifically asking about.

Comment: Ok cool, I has solved it another simpler way, I just call the function at the end of #password as when the user changes #cpassword the function gets called anyway thanks for your help :)